# How to access #1 inside conditional inside array->forEach

Tags: lasso-lang

I trying to learn captures in Lasso 9, but I am struggling to figure out how to access the `#1` local variable from within a conditional that's inside an `array->forEach` capture. Maybe my approach is all wrong. Is there a reference to the parent capture that I need to use? Following is the working code:

```
define paramstovars() => {

    local(p = web_request->params)

    #p->foreach => {
        local(i = #1)
        if(#i->type == 'pair') => {
            var(#i->first->asstring = #i->second->asstring)
        }
    }

}
```

Following is the code I am trying to get working without relying on a redundant local variable definition:

```
define paramstovars() => {

    local(p = web_request->params)

    #p->foreach => {
        if(#1->type == 'pair') => {
            var(#1->first->asstring = #1->second->asstring)
        }
    }

}
```

In this second example, I receive an error that *Position was out of range: 1 max is 0 (Error Code -1)* on the line calling `var()`.

Obvious security concerns with this custom method aside, what's the most efficient way to make #1 available inside nested conditionals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#1 is replaced within each capture — so yes, you will need to assign it to another local in order to use it in deeper captures. If you need to work with the local again try using query expressions instead:

```
 with i in web_request->params do {
    if(#i->type == 'pair') => {
        var(#i->first->asstring = #i->second->asstring)
    }
}
```

Also, I wouldn't recommend settings variables in this fashion — it posses a security risk. It would be better to store the parameters in a single variable and then potentially set specific variables from that. There's a set of tags that does something similar here: [getparam / postparam](http://www.lassosoft.com/tagswap/detail/web_request_params)

Answer (score 0):

It is my experience that #1 is consumed when called first time. At least I have never ben able to call it twice in the same capture.

If I need the value more than once I make it a local first. As you do in your example 1.

Comment: Forget all I wrote before! See my next answer

Answer (score 0):

Some experiments later.

You can call #1 several times, contrary to what  I wrote, but what trips your effort is that you have a capture inside the capture (the conditional).
The second capture will have it's own input params.

Here's a working, tested example to do what you want to do:

```
local(
    myarray = array(1, 2 = 'two', 3 = 'four', 4),
    mypairs = map
)

#myarray -> foreach => {
    if(#1-> isa(::pair)) => {
        #mypairs -> insert(#1 -> first -> asstring = #1 -> second -> asstring)
    }(#1)
}
#my pairs
```

The result will be map(2 = two, 3 = four)

The trick is the sending of the foreach param to the conditional capture : `{some code}(#1)

Now, with all that worked out. I recommend that you take a look at Ke Carltons latest addition to tagswap. It will solve the same problem way better than creating a bunch of dynamic vars as you are attempting to do:

[www.lassosoft.com/tagswap/detail/web_request_params](http://www.lassosoft.com/tagswap/detail/web_request_params)

Comment: Bugger, Ke beat me to it